# Compilation error when creating procedure which should send report by email?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I need to send result of query via email daily but I have error. Please can you help?

```sql
create or replace PROCEDURE PROC_SEND_EMAIL AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE
    l_id NUMBER;
    l_clob CLOB;
CURSOR emp_cursor IS
        SELECT
            COL_ID,COL_1,COL_2,COL_3,COL_4,COUNTRY_CODE,
            COL_5,COL_6,COL_7,COL_8,CREATE_DATE,
            VALIDATION_DATE,COMPLETION_DT,COL_9,CREATE_WEEK,CREATE_MONTH
        FROM
            V_VALIDATION_OF_COUNTRIES
            WHERE trunc(CREATE_DATE) >= trunc(sysdate-1) 
            AND trunc(CREATE_DATE) < trunc(sysdate)
            ORDER BY CREATE_DATE DESC;
    TYPE emp_data_array IS TABLE OF emp_cursor%ROWTYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
    l_emp_data_array emp_data_array;
BEGIN
    -- Fetch data into the array
    OPEN emp_cursor;
    FETCH emp_cursor BULK COLLECT INTO l_emp_data_array;
    CLOSE emp_cursor;
    -- Loop through the array and concatenate data
    FOR i IN 1..l_emp_data_array.COUNT LOOP
        l_clob := l_clob || l_emp_data_array(i).emp_data || CHR(13) || CHR(10);
    END LOOP;
    -- Send email and attach the CLOB data
    l_id := APEX_MAIL.SEND(
        p_to => 'name@mail.com',
        p_from => 'name_from@mail.com',
        p_subj => 'Report daily',
        p_body => 'Please review the attachment.',
        p_body_html => '<b>Please</b> review the attachment'
    );
    APEX_MAIL.ADD_ATTACHMENT(
        p_mail_id => l_id,
        p_attachment => l_clob,
        p_filename => 'mydata.csv',
        p_mime_type => 'text/csv'
    );
    COMMIT;
END;
END;
```

I have error that `emp_cursor is not visible`.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @Boneist The OP uses `SELECT COLUMN1,COLUMN2` into a record defined as `emp_cursor%ROWTYPE` and then tries to get `l_emp_data_array(i).emp_data`. I'm half assuming the OP has redacted some columns but not others but if they haven't then the error will be that the record does not have a `emp_data` member (as it only has `COLUMN1` and `COLUMN2`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an implicit cursor loop and then you do not need collect the values into an associative array.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC_SEND_EMAIL
AS 
  l_id NUMBER;
  l_clob CLOB;
BEGIN
  FOR r IN (
    SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2
    FROM   TABLE
  )
  LOOP
    l_clob := l_clob || r.column1 || ',' || r.column2 || CHR(13) || CHR(10);
  END LOOP;

  -- Send email and attach the CLOB data
  l_id := APEX_MAIL.SEND(
    p_to        => 'name@mail.com',
    p_from      => 'name_from@mail.com',
    p_subj      => 'Report daily',
    p_body      => 'Please review the attachment.',
    p_body_html => '<b>Please</b> review the attachment'
  );
  APEX_MAIL.ADD_ATTACHMENT(
    p_mail_id    => l_id,
    p_attachment => l_clob,
    p_filename   => 'mydata.csv',
    p_mime_type  => 'text/csv'
  );
END;
/
```

*Note: If `column1` or `column2` contain commas then you may need to escape those values when you generate the CSV.*

Comment: Thank you. I have 10 columns in query, i just gave here example. I think i need to put in array still. Can you help?

Comment: @Kris [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77986873/edit) and provide a [MRE] with the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data (note: `TABLE` is not a valid table name); an English (not code) explanation of the logic you are trying to implement when you format the table data; and provide the expected output for that sample data. I think you will find that you do not need to put the values into an array and can do it directly from the cursor (as per my answer) but without a [MRE] you have not explained why you think differently.